# Create new columns based on a tree like pattern

Tags: python, pandas, graph, networkx, graph-theory

I have the following dataframe:

```
col1      col2               
basic      c                   
c          c++                 
c++        java                
ruby                                     
php                                      
java       python              
python                                   
r                                        
c#
```

I want to create new columns based on a pattern followed in dataframe.
For example, in the above dataframe `basic->c->c++->java->python` order can be observed from col1 and col2.

**Logic:**

col1 value `basic` has `c` value in `col2`, similarly `c` value in `col1` corresponds to `c++` in col2, `c++` leads to `java` in `col2` and finally `java` to `python` in `col2`.
Remaining values in "col1" which have corresponding blanks in `col2` would be left blank in newly created columns as well. (that is, we consider only the values in "col1" which do not have blanks in `col2`).

So my output dataframe would be:

```
     col1     col2   new_col1  new_col2   new_col3   new_col4   
0   basic       c          c        c++       java     python
1       c     c++        c++       java     python         
2     c++    java       java     python                  
3    ruby                                              
4     php                                              
5    java  python     python                           
6  python                                             
7       r                                               
8       c
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved through [graph theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory) analysis. It looks like you want to obtain all [successors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_graph_theory_terms#successor) starting from each of the nodes in `col2`. For that we need to first build a [directed graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph) using the columns `col1` and `col2`. We can use networkX for that, and build a `nx.DiGraph` from the dataframe using [`nx.from_pandas_edgelist`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_edgelist.html):

```
import networkx as nx

m = df.ne('').all(1)
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df[m], 
                            source='col1', 
                            target='col2', 
                            create_using=nx.DiGraph())
```

And then we can iterate over the `nodes` in `col2`, and search for all successors starting from that node. For that we can use [`dfs_tree`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.traversal.depth_first_search.dfs_tree.html#networkx.algorithms.traversal.depth_first_search.dfs_tree), which will traverse the graph in search for the successors with a depth-first-search from source:

```
all_successors = [list(nx.dfs_tree(G, node)) for node in df.loc[m,'col2']]
```

Now we can assign back the list of longest paths with:

```
out = (df.assign(
         **pd.DataFrame(all_successors, index=df[m].index)
         .reindex(df.index)
         .fillna('')
         .add_prefix('new_col')))
```

---

```
print(out)

     col1    col2   new_col0   new_col1   new_col2   new_col3
0   basic       c          c        c++       java     python
1       c     c++        c++       java     python         
2     c++    java       java     python                  
3    ruby                                              
4     php                                              
5    java  python     python                           
6  python                                             
7       r                                               
8       c
```

---

To better explain this approach, consider instead this slightly different network, with an additional component:

[image]

As mentioned what we want here is a list of successors for each of the nodes that we have in `Col2`. For these problems there are several graph searching algorithms, which can be used to explore the branches of a graph starting from a given node. For that we can use the `depth first search` based functions available in `nx.algorithms.traversal`. In this case we want [`nx.dfs_tree`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.traversal.depth_first_search.dfs_tree.html#networkx.algorithms.traversal.depth_first_search.dfs_tree), which returns an *oriented tree* constructed through a depth-first-search starting from a specified node.

Here are some examples:

```
list(nx.dfs_tree(G, 'c++'))
# ['c++', 'java', 'python', 'julia']

list(nx.dfs_tree(G, 'python'))
# ['python', 'julia']

list(nx.dfs_tree(G, 'basic'))
# ['basic', 'php', 'sql']
```

Note that this could get quite tricker in the case of having cycles within the graph. Say there is for instance an edge between `c++` and `scala`. In this case it becomes unclear which should be the path to choose. One way could be traversing all respective paths with `nx.dfs_tree` and keeping the one of interest predefining some logic, such as keeping the longest. Though it doesn't seem like this is the case in this problem.

Comment: So check with this dataframe and see if you see any differences with yous? @pc_pyr

Comment: Thanks @yatu, runs perfect! Also I would like to understand the edited logic (the updated part) please in the DAG part, thanks again!!!

Comment: I will add some more details explaining @pc_pyr Thanks to you too, this was such an interesting one to work with :)

Comment: Great explanation !! Thanks@yatu, also does this handle integer/alphanumeric values in columns as well ?

Comment: Yes that should not be a problem @pc_pyr